# Jolt to split into multiple json

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Please help me to transform this using jolt:

**Expected Input**:

```json
{
  "sourceNode" : [ "id:source-abc", "id:source-def" ],
  "targetNode" : [ "id:target-abc", "id:target-def"  ]
}
```

Where I may have multiple source nodes and same number of target nodes. I just need to split it to multiple json.

**Expected Output**:

```json
{
  "sourceNode" : "id:source-abc",
  "targetNode" : "id:target-abc"
}
{
  "sourceNode" : "id:source-def",
  "targetNode" : "id:target-def"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // the level of the both array
        "*": { // the indexes of the array
          "@": "[#2].&2" // &2 means going 2 levels up to grab the literals "sourceNode" and "targetNode"
                         // [#2] means traversing : and the first { to reach the level of the indexes
                         //            to generate arraywise results           
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Barbaros, you are a savior :-)